# Assigning Different Values in Foreach Array in php depending on values within each array being looped over

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Right now I am using laravel to fetch okta app information from the DB. I pull these rows out and the credentials differ since there are 2 different okta apps. i.e the `client_secret` and `redirect` URI's are different for each app.

Right now I pull the 2 rows out and loop through and assign credentials in the loop but the issue is that I do not know how to differentiate the apps and assign them different credentials while looping.

Boot method in service provider where I assign credentials

```
public function boot(OktaApp $oktaApp, Repository $repository)
{
        $oktaApps = $oktaApp
            ->where('name', 'oktaApp1')
            ->orWhere('name', 'oktaApp2')
            ->get()->toArray();
            
    foreach ($oktaApps as $app) {
        //How do I assign creds dynamically based on app name?
        $repository['services.oktaApp1'] = [
            'client_id' => $app['client_id'],
            'client_secret' => $app['client_secret'],
            'redirect' =>  $app['redirect_uri'],
            'base_url' => $app['base_url'],
        ];
    }
}
```

If I die and dump the results from `$oktaApps`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "oktaApp1"
    "client_id" => "......removed for security....."
    "client_secret" => "......removed for security....."
    "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:8000/login/oktaApp1/callback"
    "base_url" => "......removed for security....."
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 2
   "name" => "oktaApp2"
    "client_id" => "......removed for security....."
    "client_secret" => "......removed for security....."
    "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:8000/login/oktaApp2/callback"
    "base_url" => "......removed for security....."
  ]
]
```

How I am manually assigning the values as of right now (working but hard coded)

```
            $repository['services.oktaApp1'] = [
                'client_id' => $app[0]['client_id'],
                'client_secret' => $app[0]['client_secret'],
                'redirect' =>  $app[0]['redirect_uri'],
                'base_url' => $app[0]['base_url'],
            ];
    
     
            $repository['services.oktaApp2'] = [
                'client_id' => $app[1]['client_id'],
                'client_secret' => $app[1]['client_secret'],
                'redirect' =>  $app[1]['redirect_uri'],
                'base_url' => $app[1]['base_url'],
            ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `$repository['services.oktaApp1']` an array of arrays so instead you make it like so.

```php
foreach ($oktaApps as $app) {
    $repository['services'][$app['name']] = [
        'client_id' => $app['client_id'],
        'client_secret' => $app['client_secret'],
        'redirect' =>  $app['redirect_uri'],
        'base_url' => $app['base_url'],
    ];
}
```

I am not sure if this will fit in your scenario so let me know.

Comment: I will try this out right now and let you know. I just saw this and thank you for your answer.

Comment: I keep getting this error  ` ``Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Config\Repository has no effect```

Comment: Can you post the code that assign the values to the configs

Comment: I just posted the code showing how I manually assign them using an index right now. Again I want to do this in a loop to prevent hard coded values. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer, there was a mistake in this line `$repository['services'][$app->name] =`